# How to change histogram of an image?

Tags: python, image-processing, histogram

I want to get a histogram of my input_image and then do some process on it and after that apply new histogram on the input_image. how can I apply new histogram on the image?

Comment: Apply a histogram? I don’t think this makes sense. Operations that modify the histogram do so by putting each pixel through some transfer function, they never compute a histogram.

Comment: i think you are talking about histogram equalization or histogram matching, see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763974/histogram-matching-of-two-images-without-using-histeq  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24094649/explanation-of-the-histogram-equalization-function-in-matlab

Comment: for python you can see this link https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_histograms/py_histogram_equalization/py_histogram_equalization.html

Comment: If you add `1` to every pixel, the histogram will move one pixel to the right if you re-compute it... other than that, I am unsure what you mean.